# Angular2 net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME for Base64 image

Tags: angular, base64

I am trying to display jpg/png images on HTML. From server I am getting Base64 string. Which I am displaying from in HTML as:

```
<md-card>
  <md-card-content>
    <img id="uploadPicture" class="uploadPicture" [src]="'data:image/jpg;base64,' +file_src ">
  </md-card-content>
  <md-card-actions>
    <input id="uploadedFile" type="file" #fileInput (change)="chooseImage(fileInput.files)"/>
    <button md-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="isUploaded" (click)="uploadPicture(fileInput.files)">{{'upload picture' | translate}}</button>
    <button md-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="isRemoved" (click)="removePicture()">{{'remove picture' | translate}}</button>
  </md-card-actions>
</md-card>
```

When I upload the picture using PUT URL, it is working fine. But when I try to download it using GET API, its giving me error as:

> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

I am getting warning also as :

> WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value

I use the sanitizer in my component as below:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.file_src!='')
    {
      this.userService.getPicture()
      .then(
      (response:any) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.file_src = response.json();
        this.file_src = this._sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, `data:image/png;base64,${this.file_src}`);
      }
      )
      .catch(
      (error:any) => {
        this.displayError();
      }
      )
    }
  }
```

But it didn't work. Can someone tell me what could be an issue?

Comment: It worked. Though I am still getting this error, I could see the image now. I have removed that if(this.file_src!='') check.

Answer (score 0):

When upload image  append http:\ or https:\ in base64string.